# Create regExp to textField in QML

Tags: c++, regex, qt, qml, textfield

I need a regExp to a textField who will receive a ip and mask, something like that: "000.000.000.000/00". It's necessary, if field is empty, return 0: example - 192.168.0.12

I have that:

```
 Custom.VisTextField{implicitWidth: 200; implicitHeight: 30
        id: ipValue
        validator:RegExpValidator
         {
           regExp:/^(([01]?[0-9]?[0-9]|2([0-4][0-9]|5[0-5]))\.){3}([01]?[0-9]?[0-9]|2([0-4][0-9]|5[0-5]))\/(([01]?[0-3]|3([0])|2([0-9]))\.)$/
         }

         inputMask:  "000.000.000.000/00;0"
    }
```

But when field is empty i receive nothing, example: 192.168..12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I search in many fonts to discover a resolution, but i realize a conflict with inputMask and regEx. I solved using something like that:

```
        Custom.VisTextField{implicitWidth: 200; implicitHeight: 30
        id: ipValue
        validator:RegExpValidator
         {
           regExp: /^(([01 ]?[ 0-9]?[0-9 ]|2([ 0-4][0-9 ]|5[ 0-5]))\.){3}([01 ]?[ 0-9]?[0-9 ]|2([ 0-4][0-9 ]|5[ 0-5]))\/(([0-2 ]?[ 0-9]|3([0 ]))\.)$/
         }

         inputMask:  "000.000.000.000/00"
    }
```